How to retrieve a number of results with the filter function
Good morning,
I use the following code to sort a list from an html table.
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#MySearch tr").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
        if (value !== '') {
            $(this).addClass("on");
            $(this).hover(function(){
                $(this).addClass("hover");
            }, function(){
                    $(this).addClass("on");
                }
            );
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("on");
            $(this).hover(function(){
                $(this).remoceClass("hover");
            });
        };
    });
});

For the moment I can only retrieve the total number with this code:
var arrayLength = $("#MySearch tr").length;

I'm trying to display the number of lines found based on my input.

"I use the following code to sort a list from an html table." - sorting and filtering are two completely different things, so please don't confuse the two.

are you aware that filter is expected to return the filtered array? and that the callback should just put in place the criteria to return true or false? why are you having side effects instead? if that strategy said before is applied, you can just use length as you stated over the returned array

Regardless of the mentioned issue regarding the filter function, if the filtering itself nevertheless "works", then $("#MySearch tr:visible").length; should probably be able to get you the number you are looking for. https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

remoceClass is not a jQuery method.

Every time this code executes an additional hover handler is added to each element -- this will just increase and increase the number of handlers, where one will potentially undo the effect of the other.

There are several issues here:

The jQuery filter method should be used for getting back a jQuery collection with elements for which the callback function returns a truthy value. Your code ignores the value that is returned, and the callback never returns a truthy value either.

keyup will not be triggered if you make changes to your input with the mouse (like drag/drop, context menu) or another device. Better use the input event.

At every keyup event, your code will attach new handlers for hover events (mouseenter, mouseleave), stacking up duplicate (or contradictory) handlers, which eat memory and processing time.

indexOf(value) > -1 is the old way of doing includes(value).

remoceClass has a typo, so that will fail.

When value == '', the else block will remove the hover class when you start hovering over a row, but it escapes me why you only want to remove it when you start hovering, and why you expect it to be there in the first place.

Every visible row will get the on class, so there seems no reason to dynamically add or remove it.

id attributes are case sensitive. It is common practice to avoid mixed case for these. Be careful with myInput with lowercase "m" and MySearch with uppercase "m"... this is asking for problems.


You can get the number of visible rows by using :visible in your selector.
Here is how it could work (I didn't touch the id naming):


$("#MySearch").on("mouseenter", "tr", function() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}).on("mouseleave", "tr", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
});

$("#myInput").on("input", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#MySearch tr").each(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().includes(value));
    });
    $("#count").text($("#MySearch tr:visible").length);
}).trigger("input");

</script></body></html>
.hover { background: yellow }
td { border: 1px solid }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput"><br>
Count: <span id="count"></span><br>

<table id="MySearch">
    <tr><td>Mexico</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Amsterdam</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Osaka</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Melbourne</td></tr>
    <tr><td>New Delhi</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Rio de Janeiro</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Brazaville</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Oslo</td></tr>
</table>




ok for your answer
it's true the code was really messy
